# R - How to set a time trigger to run a code n times?

Tags: r, time, triggers

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a kind of "time trigger" run code.
I need to run my code at a specific time for n times in a time interval.

For example, at 17 PM I need to calculate the average of a vector every seconds in a 1 minute time interval.

Can you please help me understand how to do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Hi, I use windows 7

Comment: Great, then linked post shows how this is done on Windows.

Comment: I don't know if it is what I am looking for... I'd prefer something like 

if (run_time == sys.time) {
...
}